# create table like temptable in spark 1.6

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame in `pyspark` called `df`.

I have register this `df` as `temptable`

```
df.registerTempTable('mytempTable')
```

Now I want to use create table like statement to create a table in `hive`.

```
sqlContext.sql("create table {}.{} like mytempTable".format(hivedb,table))
```

But I am getting error like below

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot recognize input near 'like' 'mytempTable' '<EOF>' in select clause; line 1 pos 59"
```

I have found a `JIRA` for this issue and looks like this issue has been fixed in `spark 2.0`.

The problem is my `spark` version is `1.6`.

Is there a work around for this issue in `spark 1.6`.

The `JIRA` link is here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5720

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
sqlContext.sql("create table {}.{} as select * from mytempTable ".format(hivedb,table))
```

or:

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("{}.{}".format(hivedb,table))
```

Comment: `sqlContext.sql("create table {}.{} as select * from mytempTable ".format(hivedb,table))` this will create table with data. I want only just the table to be created without data

Comment: you can use `createDataFrame(data, schema=None, samplingRatio=None)` to create an empty data frame and then `df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("{}.{}".format(hivedb,table))` for further reference use this link https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.udf